# Firebase function NodeJS throwing parsing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm brand new to NodeJS and I am trying to deploy my first firebase function. I validate the following code online and it looks good but it keeps throwing a parse error when I try to deploy it. Where is my mistake?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationToFCMToken = functions.firestore.document('Chats/{ChatKeyId}/messages').onWrite(async(event) -> {
    const receiverId = event.after.get('receiverId');
    const senderId = event.after.get('senderId');

    const userRef = db.collection('Users');

    const receiverDoc = await.userRef.where('userId', '==', receiverId).get;
    if(receiverDoc.empty) {
        console.log('receiverDoc empty');
        return;
    }
    receiverDoc.forEach(doc => {
        const fcmToken = doc.fcmToken;
    });

    const senderDoc = await.userRef.where('userId', '==', senderId).get;
    if (senderDoc.empty) {
        console.log('senderDoc empty')
        return;
    }
    senderDoc.forEach(doc => {
        const name = doc.name;
    });

    const content = event.after.get('content');
    let userDoc = await admin.firestore().doc('users/${uid}').get();
    let fcmToken = userDoc.get('fcm');

    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: 'New Message',
            body: 'New message from ${name}',
        },
        token: fcmToken,
    }

    let response = away admin.messaging().send(message);
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: What error? Look, if you want an answer, be detailed. "parse error" doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a dot in the wrong place and you are missing parenthesis and other problems:

- The get function of a firestore document should be `get()`:

  ```
  // Wrong
  userRef.where('userId', '==', senderId).get;
  // Correct
  userRef.where('userId', '==', senderId).get();
  ```
- Replace every occurrence of `await.` with `await` :

  ```
  // Wrong
  const receiverDoc = await.userRef.where('userId', '==', receiverId).get();
  // Correct
  const receiverDoc = await userRef.where('userId', '==', receiverId).get();
  ```
- Use **backticks** for templating:

  ```
  let a = `users/${uid}`    // NOTE!!!!!!!! ` not ' or "
  ```
- What do the `forEach` loops do?

Be careful and check your code again.

Comment: Be careful, there are other weird things in your code, but at least now it should work.